# Differences between two versions of the same file in nonadjacent commits in git

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a repository with some commits:

```
latest-commit
before-latest-commit
...
some-old-commit
```

Let's say it has a file called `1.file`

Let's say it looks like this across the various commits:

some-old-commit:

```
a=1;
```

before-latest-commit:

```
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
```

latest-commit:

```
a=1;
c=3;
```

Can I somehow view the differences between the `latest-commit` and `some-old-commit` versions of `1.file` (preferably on github) and have the line `c=3;` marked as new, while what went on with b would be left out (as it's irrelevant).

This seems like something basic, but I wasn't able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
git diff some-old-commit..latest-commit -- 1.file
```

You'd not be able to run this on github so first fetch from github in your local repository.

Comment: And if `latest-commit` is really the latest commit and there's no change in the work tree, you can shorten it like this: `git diff some-old-commit 1.file`